# Push notification with APNs from back to Expo in development

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, apple-push-notifications

I'm using APNs to push notifications from back end to my iOS app. It works fine in production. But before push new app version, I would test it with the same configuration using APNs, in development environment with the expo app.

1. I catch the device push token from my app through Expo, with `getDevicePushTokenAsync`.
2. I have conditions on my API, if it's development environment I send notification to `https://api.sandbox.push.apple.com`
3. I set `experienceId` and `scopeKey` props in the payload notification with `@expoUsername/projectSlug`.

But when I try to push notification it doesn't work: `{"reason":"BadDeviceToken"}`

*Note that if I make no difference between production and development (send to `https://api.push.apple.com` and no more props in the payload) I get `{"reason":"DeviceTokenNotForTopic"}`.*

Comment: Nope never, sorry

Comment: I just faced that an Expo Development Build app is delivering production device token through `getDevicePushTokenAsync` and so notifications should be addressed like in production (via APNS and not APNS_SANDBOX)